# Article reads poorly/weird/weirdly - Are any of the given sentences grammatically incorrect? If so, why?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adverbs

1. The article reads poorly.
2. The article reads weird.
3. The article reads weirdly.

To me, a non-native speaker, the first sentence seems fine, the second one seems like it could be used in informal conversations, and the third one just seems wrong. However, Grammarly suggests using "weirdly" in the third sentence is not wrong. Is that correct? Also, are any of these sentences grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

The first is fine, though I would probably want to know in what way it was poor. The writer's syntax was poor or their reasoning was poor, for example. I suppose without further specification I would assume it sounded clunky or that it was much harder to say aloud than to read silently.

The second would be colloquial because of "weird" as a zero-marked adverb (which some would say *is* indeed ungrammatical), but it's not very likely because "reads" is not used in colloquial diction. You could say it sounds weird or looks weird or feels weird. These options are by far the most natural of all the ones proposed.

The third is a little questionable. I wouldn't say it's impossible, but it sure "reads weirdly" itself. The specificity problem mentioned above only gets worse with the word "weirdly". What about the way it reads can be weird? I guess if I were forced to assign a meaning to it, I would assume that the sentences don't sound the way you'd expect based on the way they're written, maybe.

Comment: The article reads weirdly. sounds like the article is reading...John, however, could read weirdly...

Comment: @Lambie True, it's odd enough that one almost has to resort to that definition instead.